# Minerals and Vitamins: Does RDI balances in 2 days of opposite quantity intake?

Tags: micronutrients

I wonder if RDI (or DV) balances in 2 days of opposite quantity intake?

For example lets say Vitamin A:

```
Day 1 intake against RDI = 10%
Day 2 intake against RDI = 190%
```

So, will this balance it out for both days? or will one day it be dangerously insufficient and the other day if will be dangerously overdosed?

What if its over multiple days?

Comment: Please add where and how you researched this and add more details to what your question is about. E. g.: What is RDI and DV? Also,the question itself isn't very clear to me.

Comment: The answer is different for different vitamins. Also, are you talking about taking supplements, or about what you eat?

Comment: @KateGregory lets just say Vitamin A for simple example. and does it matter a lot if its supplement or if its natural? if it does matter a lot then to keep it further simple lets just talk about eating it via regular food such as carrot

Comment: Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitamin from top to bottom, especially the parts about fat and water soluble, effects of deficiency and excess intake, and recommended levels. Then come and edit your question to be more precise.